# Will the QR codes I create using the qr4office add-in ever expire?

Tags: office-addins

@user:678505

I have recently discovered many free QR creators expire the generated QR codes after a period of time.  If I install the qr4office add-in to Microsoft, will the QR codes I generate eventually expire?

I want the QR code to be static.

Comment: The app doesn't do anything with the QR codes, it simply encodes them into QR form and then creates an image out of it. So no, they will continue to work forever, so long as the link that they point to still exists. Moreover, since they're created as regular images, even if you eventually uninstall the app or even if the app were to eventually be removed from the store, the images would work in perpetuity.

Comment: Non-programming questions go to the https://superuser.com/ web site.

Comment: Thank you Michael, your response is greatly appreciated!